# switching scenes in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm writing a little something in libgdx to learn more about the platform. Currently, I have a simple generated world consists of tiles, which are just blocks of texture drawn to the screen. It's a simple setup, but I'm wondering how would I go about switching to a different "scene". For instance, just imagine a player, walking around in a grass field, enters a cave, and bam, he is in the cave. The world behind him has transitioned from a grass field to a cave (essentially, from one generated world to another).

I'm not very sure how libgdx handles scenes, so if anyone can share some tips, I'd appreciate it.

NOTE: I know this is a very broad question; right now I'm not asking for a specific solution but rather some tips to help me approach the idea I'm going after.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have everything in the main game class? If so you can move each scene into its separate scene which each implements the Screen class.

For example

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public abstract class AbstractScene implements Screen
{

protected Game game;
protected Stage mainStage;
protected Stage uiStage;
public final int viewWidth;
public final int viewHeight;
protected boolean paused;

public AbstractScene(Game g, int viewWidth, int viewHeight)
{
    game = g;
    this.viewWidth = viewWidth;
    this.viewHeight = viewHeight;
    mainStage = new Stage(new FitViewport(viewWidth, viewHeight));
    uiStage = new Stage(new FitViewport(viewWidth, viewHeight));

    create();
}

public abstract void create();
public abstract void update(float dt);

@Override
public void render(float dt)
{
    uiStage.act(dt);
    if (!paused)
    {
        mainStage.act(dt);
        update(dt);
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mainStage.draw();
    uiStage.draw();
}
}
```

Now all you need to do is call the following function whenever you need to swap scenes.

```
game.setScreen(new ScreenClass());
```